# Clicking the buttonimage should go to search.php

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        $("input[class=search]").bind("keyup",function(){
            $.get("search.php?search="+$(this).val(), 
                  function(data){
                      if(data==1) {
                          alert("this is valid search")
                      } else {
                          alert("this is a right user search");
                      }
                  }
            );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Below is the button image code

```
<table width="165" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/search_box_left_im.png" width="3" height="28" />
        </td>
        <td class="inputbox_bg" width="118px">
            <input type="text" name="search" class="username">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="image" onclick="loadXMLDoc()" src="images/search_go_btn.png" border="0" width="44" height="28" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is going to the function but not executing the ajax code

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
$("input[class=search]").bind("keyup",function(){
 $.get("search.php?search="+$(this).val(),function(data){
    if(data==1){
      alert("this is valid search")
    }else{
      alert("this is a right user search");
    }
})

})
}
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
$("input[name=search]").bind("keyup",function(){ //<- important bit here
 $.get("search.php?search="+$(this).val(),function(data){
    if(data==1){
      alert("this is valid search")
    }else{
      alert("this is a right user search");
    }
})

})
}
</script>
```

Comment: Lucas it is not working , i kept a alert message in the javascript but alert is working not going to search.php

Comment: use `console.log(data)` to inspect the data to find out why

Comment: I am not a specialist in developing the ajax code just i copied it somewhere. Pls help me so that i can able to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".username").keyup(function(event){ //<- important bit here
 $.get("search.php?search="+$(this).val(),function(data){
    if(data==1){
      alert("this is valid search")
    }else{
      alert("this is a right user search");
    }

   });
});

$('input[type=image]').click(function() {
  $('.username').keyup();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'search.php?search='+$(".username").val(),
        success: function(data){                
          if(data==1) {
              alert("this is valid search")
          } else {
              alert("this is a right user search");
          }  
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Suresh the function is stopping here only $.ajax({

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input type="image" ... />` is a submit button for the form.
What you want to do is change its default behaviour (submitting form) to alternative - execute some code.
Here is a good question about this: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Besides that, you are assigning an event listener twice - once in your  `<input onclick="" />` and second time inside the event handler `$("input[class=search]").bind()`

Try removing your `<input onclick="" />` and define event listener in `$(document).ready()`:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[class=search]").bind("keyup",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get("search.php?search="+$(this).val(),function(data){
            if(data==1){
                alert("this is valid search")
            }else{
                alert("this is a right user search");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
...
<input type="image" src="images/search_go_btn.png" border="0" width="44" height="28" />
...
```